# Definition of entity in EER Diagram

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-framework-core, entity-relationship, diagram

I have to write the conceptual diagram of a DBMS.

I have a very simple, maybe banal question, but I found no answers on the internet.

This DBMS will be used by the secretaries of a school. In this schema there are entities like students, courses, exams and so on.

Can I also add the entity "**secretary**", even if the secretaries will be the ones who will use the DBMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An entity is a type of thing to store in your database system.

Each different entity type has an identifying key, and a distinct set of attributes. For example, a user entity might have some identification number, and perhaps attributes for login name, password, creation date, email, real name, etc.

Then you have to ask if a secretary is just one of the users, or is it a distinct entity?

The answer is driven by whether a secretary has unique attributes. Is there some fact about each secretary that needs to be stored in the database, that no other user has?

If not, then perhaps secretary is just an example of a user entity. Maybe it would be helpful to make the user entity have an attribute column to note the type of user (secretary, administrator, faculty, parent, etc.), but not create a separate entity unless the category of secretary needs their own attributes.

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask you a single question? If I have two entities CUSTOMERS and SCHEDULE (connected by 1:1), during the conceptual phase is it an error to add among the attributes of SCHEDULE "CustomerID" ? ( I know that in a second phase it will be an external key, but I am wondering about the er-diagram.) Or it would be useless and redundant?

Comment: Depends on whether you're designing a logical ER diagram or a physical ER diagram. https://www.visual-paradigm.com/tutorials/compare-logical-physical-erd.jsp

Comment: conceptual ER diagram, like this https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-Complete-EER-diagram_fig3_220468046 , but with attributes

Comment: In a logical ER diagram, I would think the foreign key column is implied by the relationship.

Comment: I momentarily added the picture of what I am referring to in the question

Comment: I'm wondering why you would have a reference to the Customer in the Schedule table in either diagram. Why not go the other way: add a reference to the schedule in the Customer table?

Answer (score 1):

Sure your can. You can, and in fact, you should throw everything on your conceptual design whiteboard that has any relevance to your system. And do some contemplation of where the chips might fall.

Usually you would have a "User" in your system, and that "User" might be a "Secretary" but very quickly you have other "Users", which would include the "Students" and possibly "Managers" and "Advisors".

The whole point about a word as general as "Entity" in an Entity-Relationship Model is that it is general and anything whatsoever of interest to your problem can be an "Entity" in that sense.

Comment: Thank you! may I ask you a thing? I am working on the conceptual ER diagram of a DBMS. This DABMS will be used by some Managers, that will control (registrate and modify accounts) of customers.

In my diagram I have the two entities "MANAGER" and "CUSTOMER". Is it necessary to connect them with a relationship (M:N), to specify that the Managers are those who will manage the customers' account, or this relationship is unnecessary?

Comment: @Jenny it is completely up to whether you have a business need to track that relationship or not. It sound like you have that need or you are thinking about it. However, you can cross that bridge when you get there. If you have a decent model that isn't "denormalizing" a bunch of stuff for premature "performance" heuristics, you can just keep it simple now and add that relationship when you need it in your next version. One thing you want to consider then, is, that the assignment of manager to customer accounts will change when managers leave or are promoted to other positions.